# Does Python csv writer always use DOS end-of-line characters?

Tags: python, csv, line-endings, writer

I realize that the **csv** library in Python always generates DOS end-of-line characters. Even if I use the `'wb'` mode, even if I use Linux.

```
import csv

f = open('output.txt', 'wb');
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow([2,3,4]);
f.close()
```

The above code always uses `'\r\n'` as the end of line separator.  How can I make it use use `'\n'` only?

Comment: The CSV MIME spec mandates CRLF as the line delimiter: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc4180

Comment: I believe the csv *reader* always does and can't be changed, but you're only asking about the *writer*, whose default can be changed.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

You can [give your `writer`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.writer) instance a custom [`lineterminator`](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) argument in the constructor:

```
writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator="\n")
```

Comment: can lineterminator be given as combination of two characters ?

Comment: @user1479571 If you follow the link to the documentation for `lineterminator`, it says that it is a string, and the default value is `'\r\n'`. So yes.

Answer (score 34):

As [Niklas answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845731/4794), the [lineterminator argument](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.lineterminator) lets you choose your line endings. Rather than hard coding it to `'\n'`, make it platform independent by using your platform's [line separator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.linesep): `os.linesep`. Also, make sure to specify `newline=''` for Python 3 (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9845681/does-python-csv-writer-always-use-dos-end-of-line-characters#comment76482943_29976091) comment).

```py
import csv
import os

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator=os.linesep)
    writer.writerow([2, 3, 4])
```

#### Old solution (Python 2 only)

In Python 2, use `'wb'` mode (see the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer)).

```py
import csv
import os

with open('output.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, lineterminator=os.linesep)
    writer.writerow([2, 3, 4])
```

For others who find this post, don't miss the `'wb'` if you're still using Python 2. (In Python 3, this problem is handled by Python). You won't notice a problem if you're missing it on some platforms like GNU/Linux, but it is important to open the file in [binary mode](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#open) on platforms where that matters, like Windows. Otherwise, the csv file can end up with line endings like `\r\r\n`. If you use the `'wb'` and `os.linesep`, your line endings should be correct on all platforms.

Comment: so even if you make the writer "*platform independent*", your script is still platform dependent because you need to open it in binary, but only where necessary ? If I try `wb` on linux I get an error for `writer.writeheader()`

Comment: I just tried it on Ubuntu 16.04 using both `writer` and `DictWriter` with `wb`, @CiprianTomoiaga, and it works fine for me. I suggest you post a new question with a code sample and the error message, then add a comment here with a link to your question.

Comment: @CiprianTomoiaga This doesn't work with Python 3. The CSV module assumes that it can write normal strings and this isn't the case anymore if you open the file with `'wb'` (you would get a `TypError`). Thus, you have to open the file like this: `f = open('output.csv', 'w', newline='')` when you use Python 3. See also the [Python 3 CSV documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.writer).

Comment: Consider too that the main purpose of CSV in general is as an interchange format that works between dissimilar systems. So while using `lineterminator=os.linesep` will produce CSV that's suited to the system on which this script runs, that also means the CSV produced is different depending on where the script runs; neither of which is necessarily right for the system on which the CSV is consumed. So "platform independent" for the consumer might mean sticking to a single standard rather than varying with the OS of the producer.

Comment: While I agree that using the OS separator is normally the best option, the one place I would use "\n" is when running Python in Git Bash on Windows, or you get mixed line terminators.