# Python Write a list into csv, can't put values into a column

Tags: python, csv

I have this list of countries:

```
country = ['Togo', 'Nauru', 'Palestine, State of', 'Malawi']
```

I'm trying to write this into a csv:

```
with open('temp.csv', 'wt') as output_write:
    csvout = csv.writer(output_write)
    csvout.writerow(country)
    output_write.close()
```

However the output puts the values into a row rather than a column in csv. Can someone please let me know how to change it?

Thanks in advance!

---

I followed some of the suggestions below and the output has empty lines between rows:

[image]

The code I used:

```
import csv
country = ['Togo', 'Nauru', 'Palestine, State of', 'Malawi']
with open('temp.csv', 'wt') as output_write:
    csvout = csv.writer(output_write)
    for item in country:
        csvout.writerow((item, ))
```

---

Update:

I figured the reason that I'm getting an empty line because each row is because windows interpret a new line differently. The code that finally work for me is:

```
import csv
country = ['Togo', 'Nauru', 'Palestine, State of', 'Malawi']
with open('temp.csv', 'w', newline = '') as output_write:
    csvout = csv.writer(output_write)
    for item in country:
        csvout.writerow((item, ))
```

Found a related post regarding the empty row:

[python empty row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3348460/csv-file-written-with-python-has-blank-lines-between-each-row)

Comment: The name of the function you are calling is `writerow`. Why do you expect that to write a column?

Comment: I agree with @Shadow, the function's name is clearly that it write a row rather than column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to iterate through the list if you want to write each item to a separate line:

```
import csv

country = ['Togo', 'Nauru', 'Palestine, State of', 'Malawi']

with open('temp.csv', 'wt') as output_write:
    csvout = csv.writer(output_write, delimiter=',')
    for c in country:
         csvout.writerow([c])
```

Comment: It may or may not cause an error - but the `with` usage closes the file. Doing it manually is either erroneous or redundant.

Comment: Thank you. However this produces an empty line between each record. Any way to eliminate the empty lines?

Comment: @vivi11130704 I don't see empty lines in my case (except the ending one).

Comment: I update my original post to include a screenshot of what I'm getting. Not sure why I'm getting different results than everyone else. I'm using jupyter notebook.

Comment: @Shadow it won't crash, as I found out :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39600786/why-can-you-close-a-file-object-more-than-once

Comment: @vivi11130704 Can you double check by opening the csv file using text editor / other IDE? I'm also using Jupyter notebook.

Comment: @vivi11130704 open the file in `wb` mode, not `w`. On Windows, writing to CSV will include blank lines if you don't open in `wb` mode.

Comment: @roganjosh fair enough. Guess it's the second one then :P

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
country = ['Togo', 'Nauru', 'Palestine, State of', 'Malawi']
with open('temp.csv', 'wt') as output_write:
    csvout = csv.writer(output_write, lineterminator='\n')
    for item in country:
        csvout.writerow((item, ))
```

Comment: That's much better :)

Comment: Thank you. However this produces an empty line between each record. Any way to eliminate the empty lines?

Comment: No it's not generating any empty lines @vivi11130704. I just ran it

Comment: @vivi11130704: I have run the code in Jupyter notebook. The csv generated does not have empty lines. Maybe the problem of your csv reader? Can you open generated CSV file in a plain text editor?

Comment: To prevent empty lines, use `csvout = csv.writer(output_write, lineterminator="\n")`. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9845731/4860123)

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
import csv

countries = ['Togo', 'Nauru', 'Palestine, State of', 'Malawi']

with open('temp.csv', 'w') as output_write:
    csvout = csv.writer(output_write, lineterminator='\n')
    for country in countries:
         csvout.writerow([country])
```

[image]